# Error on "Cannot read property 'value' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, html

I know there are already many posts about this problem, but I just can't understand why this is generated, I understand what it is, but I don't know how to fix it.

In the HTML page i have this:

```
<footer>
<form method="post" action="#" name="Frazioni">

<table border="0">
<tr><td>Inserire il numero di eventuali esponenti negativi: </td>
<td><input type="num" name="frazioni" onkeyup="AggiungiRigaF(this)"/></td></tr>
</table>

<span id='box_frazioni'>
<!-- Box che conterrà le righe aggiunte -->
</span>
</form>
</footer>
```

and in the js page i have this:

```
function AggiungiRigaF(nrighe){
    var frazione = parseInt(nrighe.value);
    var boxf = document.getElementById('box_frazioni');
    if(isNaN(frazione)==true){
        boxf.innerHTML='';
    }else{
        var righef = new Array();
        for(i=0; i<frazione; i++){
                righef[i]="Inserisci la posizione dell'esponente negativo: <input type='text' name='posfraz' "+i+" size='10' maxlength='10'/><br/>";
        }
        boxf.innerHTML=righef;
    }
```

}

In another function I try to "recall" the value of "posfraz" with the command `parseInt(document.Frazioni.posfraz[j].value)`, but the above error is generated.
Thank you and I apologize in advance for any errors, it is my first post.

Comment: there's not "Frazioni" in that document

Comment: `document.Frazioni` is undefined, which is what gives you the error. What are you trying to do, and what is `posfraz` supposed to be?

Comment: VTC.  this example code  has multiple issues  please reduce it to the smallest code fragment that can demostrate the problem you want answered.

Comment: I suggest you look at the structure generated by the javascript code, it is probably not what you are expecting,  get that working correctly first.

Comment: I hadn't entered the whole code well, now it's right

Comment: @Rahul posfraz should be a form created by javascript in the html page, from which I must then take the inserted value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is difficult to figure out exactly what you mean, in part due to the non-English variable names. However, I think I know what you want.

If I understand correctly, you wish to get the value of the input whose `name` attribute is `frazioni`. Assuming this is the only input with that specific `name` attribute, you could use:

```
document.getElementsByName('frazioni')[0].value
```

It is better practice to instead give the input an id and use `document.getElementById`, though.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the error - rewrite your expression like this

```js
 parseInt((((document.Frazioni || {}).posfraz || [])[j || 0] || {}).value || 0)
```

and make sure that `j` is not undefined and not larger than the size of the array.

Comment: Even if I write 0 instead of j it gives me an error